# Copy Directories with SSIS

Tags: ssis, subdirectory

I am using SSIS with Visual Studio 2012.

I am using variables to make folders and folders within folders.

The parent folder is static **VarFolderPath** = c:\Source\test\

the first subdirectory within it is dynamic based on yyyymm. I use the following expression to make this folder stores in the variable VarFolderName.

```
@[User::VarFolderPath]+RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("yy" , GETDATE()), 4) +  (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE())
```

Within **VarFolderName** I then make four other folders CLI, Day3, INF, PRI. That is all working

[image: Make Folders]

I then want to copy CLI, INF, and PRI within the Day3 folder. I want two versions of CLI, INF and PRI. Oned irectly in VarFolderName, and another in Day3. I could make more variables to accomplish this, but since I already made the directories I was hoping to copy them. However using File System Task > Copy Directory does not copy folders, it copies all files within folders.

Thus other than adding three additional variables is there a way to leverage the directories I have already made (CLI,INF, PRI) and place copies of them in Day3 shown as numbers 5,6,7 below.

- The end goal

  1. VarFolderName\CLI
  2. VarFolderName\INF
  3. VarFolderName\PRI
  4. VarFolderName\Day3
  5. VarFolderName\Day3\CLI
  6. VarFolderName\Day3\INF
  7. VarFolderName\Day3\PRI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file system task is pretty limited in SSIS - it is really intended for the most basic operations.  Even with what you have so far, it is getting a bit complicated compared to what you could do in a script task.  Please check out this code example and try rewriting this in c# or vb:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

What about using xcopy via an Execute Process Task?

To do this, configure the task with *Executable* set to `cmd.exe` and *Arguments* equal to `/C` followed by the full command line you want to execute. For example, to copy the PRI directory to Day3\PRI, with destination directories created as needed, use `/C xcopy /I /E PRI Day3\PRI`.

If you'd like to use a single Execute Process Task to copy all three directories, try *Arguments* of `\C xcopy /I /E CLI Day3\CLI & xcopy /I /E INF Day3\INF & xcopy /I /E PRI Day3\PRI`.